# best way to create in memory db?

Tags: neo4j

Is it the correct way to create a in memory db using neo4j ? So that traverse query will hit only cache and not the disk .

**approach - 1** : I tried with this :

```
package com.test;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.FileUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CreateDBFactory {

    private static GraphDatabaseService graphDb = null;
    public static final String DB = "test/db";

    public static GraphDatabaseService createInMemoryDB() {
        System.out.println("- Inside createInMemoryDB() - ");
        if (null == graphDb) {
            synchronized (GraphDatabaseService.class) {
                if (null == graphDb) {
                    System.out.println(" - Inside if clause -");
                    final Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();
                    config.put("neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory", "50M");
                    config.put("string_block_size", "60");
                    config.put("array_block_size", "300");
                    graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
                        .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(DB).setConfig(config)
                        .newGraphDatabase();

                    registerShutdownHook(graphDb);
                }
            }
        }
        return graphDb;
    }

    private static void registerShutdownHook(final GraphDatabaseService graphDb) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                graphDb.shutdown();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void clearDb() {
        try {
            if (graphDb != null) {
                graphDb.shutdown();
                graphDb = null;
            }
            FileUtils.deleteRecursively(new File(DB));
            } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

**Approach -2**  :  Using Neo4jBasicDocTest class.

Here `new ImpermanentDatabaseBuilder()` is not creating the target/test-data/impermanent-db folder. So not able to test " Nancy" node is created or not .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neo4j doesn't have an 'in memory' mode in the sense that all data always stored in memory and no disk storage is used. `ImpermanentGraphDatabase` is the closest you'll find to anything like that, but that just creates a data directory at random and will delete it when it is shutdown.

If you are okay with using disk, you can use the above `ImpermanentGraphDatabase`, and just set the cache of neo4j to be really high. This will make everything be stored in memory, as well as on disk.

Comment: thanks Nicholas. :) One thing I want to know - after the above steps if I fire a query then will it first look from memory and then from disk. Is it ? I mean in the first place memory cache is used .

Comment: Yes. Neo4j will hit cache first, and if not present, it will hit the disk.